# Excel VBA how to return variable from function

Tags: excel, vba

Example of the code:

```
Sub

   Dim NOSSPrefix As String
   NOSSPrefix = Cells(1, 6).Value
   NOSSSpecific(NOSSPrefixSpec)

End Sub
```

---

```
Function NOSSSpecific(NOSSPrefixSpec)

   If NOSSPrefixSpec = "6" Or NOSSPrefixSpec = "17" Or NOSSPrefixSpec = "19" Then
       NOSSPrefix = NOSSPrefixSpec        
   Else
       NOSSPrefix = "999"
   End If

End Function
```

---

Tried alreaddy return, set, ... 
Just want to return the NOSSPrefix back from the function to the routine above.

Comment: Add `NOSSSpecific = NOSSPrefix ` as the last line in the Function

Comment: Replacing NOSSPrefix with the function name NOSSSpecific would make it return either of the 2 values.

Comment: AS a suggestion; I would add Option Explicit at the top of your module.  Not declaring your variables is a bad habit.

Comment: ^^ `Option Explicit` would pick up the fact that your main subroutine is passing a variable (`NOSSPrefixSpec`) to the function even though that variable had never been assigned a value previously - the previous line is setting a variable called `NOSSPrefix`.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim NOSSPrefixSpec As String
    NOSSPrefixSpec = "12"
    Debug.Print NOSSSpecific(NOSSPrefixSpec) //Returns "999"
End Sub

Function NOSSSpecific(NOSSPrefixSpec As String) As String
    If NOSSPrefixSpec = "6" Or NOSSPrefixSpec = "17" Or NOSSPrefixSpec = "19" Then
        NOSSSpecific = NOSSPrefixSpec
    Else
        NOSSSpecific = "999"
    End If
End Function
```

Note:

- You have to define `NOSSPrefix`. I changed it to `NOSSPrefixSpec`
- I've explicitly added `String` as the function argument type and return value